# How to count occurrences of a character in a String in java

Tags: java, string, decimal

Can someone tell me, how can I do an if-clause, that say me how often I used the decimal seperator in this String.

i.e.: 1234,56,789

Comment: do you want to count the occurance of `,` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to count the occurrences of `,` in the string?

Comment: Where is the decimal separator in that string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
String number = "1234,56,789";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
    if (number.charAt(i) == ',')
        count++;
// count holds the number of ',' found
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Thats fine for me :)

Comment: I have used CountMatches method in below API and its a handy tool. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 9):

```
String number = "1234,56,789";
int commaCount = number.replaceAll("[^,]*", "").length();
```

Comment: This is a great solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simpliest way is to exucute a `String.split(",")` and count the size of array.

So the instruction willl look like this :

```
String s = "1234,56,789";
int numberofComma = s.split(",").length;
```

Regards, Éric

Comment: Think this example would return 3 instead of 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use an non-if-clause, you can do :

```
int count = number.split(",").length
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any if-clause, just use

```
String s = "1234,56,78";
System.out.println(s.split(",").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class OccurenceOfChar {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter any word");
    String s=br.readLine();

    char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
    Map map=new HashMap();


    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<ch.length;j++)
        {
            if(ch[i]==ch[j])
                count++;
        }
     map.put(ch[i], count);


    }
    Iterator it=map.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry pairs=(Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println("count of "+pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
    }





    }
}
```